# 日本のは? Reason for の in this sentence

Tags: particle-の

I came across this sentence in the Japanese Try! book and I could not make out of it why の was used, what was the purpose. I understand の can act as a modifier but 日本ん on it's own is already a noun.

**日本のは**ちょっと高いですが、とてもいいです。

Just saying 日本はちょと高いですが、とてもいいです　is more straightforward and simpler. I don't get what の adds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question.

Let's start with your *more straightforward and simpler* sentence.

> 日本はちょと高いですが、...

This says

> As for Japan, it's a bit expensive....

where *it* means *Japan*.

But that's not what the original sentence is saying.  The original sentence is

> 日本のはちょっと高いですが、

which can be translated as

> The Japanese one is a bit expensive,...

There is context that is missing here.  There is something that's being talked about.  Perhaps it's a nice sweater, セーター, you like and you have a choice between a variety of sweaters one of which is Japanese.  So, the sentence could have been

> 日本のセーターはちょっと高いですが

But if it's already understood that you're talking about sweaters, you can omit セーター and just say 日本の, *the Japanese one*.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes it much more clearer for me know. I spent some hours looking at the sentence and trying to make sense out of it, I could not find online much explanation either.  Much appreciated.